# How to access Spring Boot Actuator (Production-ready features) in a spring boot ws

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-ws

I have initialized a P.O.C. based on the excellent 
[spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/](http://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/)

The mater is that the ws initialization disable all the Spring Boot Actuator (/env, /health etc ...) and more generally static and dynamic resource ( CSS / @Controller ... )

I have found that the problem come from the code the declaration of the dispatcherServlet bean:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(
        ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}   

@Bean(name = "createEL")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11DefinitionCreateEL(
        XsdSchema creatElSchema) {

    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CreateELPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace(NamespaceURI.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE_URI);
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(createELSchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}
[...]
```

It hooks everything... And I don't know how to tell to spring to let some URL works/pass ...

Thanks !

Comment: I have edited my post after the Date Answer

Answer (score 2):

If you avoid using the bean name "dispatcherServlet" for the WS dispatcher it should all work (you switched off the default dispatcher by using that bean name) - it actually already says that in the guide, by the way. I updated it to do the opposite (not replace the default dispatcher), so maybe it's easier to understand that way?

Comment: Thanks Dave , it could be : `public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(` instead of `public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(`